# Jenkins shell script: sed: -e expression #1, char 54: unterminated `s' command

Tags: bash, jenkins, sed

```
  stage('adjust Dockerfile') {
    steps {
      script {
            TAG = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'echo 123456')
            sh 'sed -i "s/name:TAG/name:\"${TAG}\"/g" Dockerfile'

      }
    }
  }
```

Result is that variable Tag is not replaced in the sh command in the Jenkinsfile.

```
+ sed -i s/name:TAG/name:/g Dockerfile
```

Same result if I change to

```
            TAG = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'echo 123456')
            sh 'sed -i "s/name:TAG/name:${TAG}/g" Dockerfile'
```

If I change the quotation marks like this

```
            TAG = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'echo 123456')
            sh "sed -i 's/name:TAG/name:${TAG}/g' Dockerfile"
```

I got the variable TAG replaced with the correct value but got a issue with sed.

````
+ sed -i s/name:TAG/name:123456
/g Dockerfile
sed: -e expression #1, char 22: unterminated `s' command```
````

Comment: What if you use `sh '''sed -i "s,name:TAG,name:$TAG,g" Dockerfile'''`? Do you know the `$TAG` value?

Comment: `[Pipeline] sh
+ sed -i s,name:TAG,name:,g Dockerfile` It's still not replacing variable TAG

Comment: I suspect your real script uses, instead of `echo 123456`, something that prints a forwards slash?

Comment: I test exactly with the exact setup shown above. I used this to elimimate uses with special characcters.

Comment: Oh, Wiktor's suggestion would have fixed the problem. Hmmm.

Comment: I'Ve testd Wiktor's suggestion but without luck. It returs `[Pipeline] sh + sed -i s,name:TAG,name:,g Dockerfile`in console output.

Comment: fix any issues found by https://shellcheck.net and then update your Q. Good luck.

Comment: It seems to be an issue with string replacement in Jenkinsfile which uses double quotes and sed in shell command which also needs double quotes.

Comment: 100+ Q/A when I searched for `[jenkins] shell quoting` . Maybe they can help? Sorry, don't use jenkins (yet). Good luck.

Comment: where did you search? didn’t get it

Comment: here, on StackOverflow, in the search bar near the top of the page?  ALSO I noticed that your original error message makes it look like the value for `$TAG` has a `\r` or `\n` embedded at the end, which would be normal for `echo`ed output. Try `TAG = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'printf 123456')` instead.

Comment: AND sometimes quoting problems such as your can be dealt with by dbl-ing up between single and dbl-quotes as illustrated in these 2 bits of code 1) `eval echo "'"'"some stuff"'"'"` which returns `"some stuff"` 2) `eval echo '"'"'some stuff'"'"'` which returns `'some stuff'`. In this example `eval` stands in place of the `jenkins` processing, but this is just a general observation and can easily be tripped up. Surround either example like `set -vx ; eval ...; set +vx` to see how the shell is scanning and processing your cmd line. Good luck.

Comment: Looks like I found a solution. But I don't know what'S the difference between echo and printf. I've changed to the following code. ```TAG = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'printf 123456')
sh 'sed -i "s/name:TAG/name:${TAG}/g" Dockerfile'``` this returns the variable as expected. `FROM name:123456` Thanks to the suggestion from @Benjamin W.

Comment: That was @shellter's idea ;) The difference between `echo` and `printf` (or one of the differences) is that `printf` doesn't append a newline at the end of the string.

Comment: Yes, that is key here: the newline ruined the command. It is not the first time I see this issue with a newline in sed used in jenkins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace `echo 123456` with `printf 123456` as `echo` adds a trailing newline at the end (which ruins the sed command later), and you must use double quotes around the sed command in order to interpolate variables inside it:

Use

```
TAG = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'printf 123456')
sh 'sed -i "s/name:TAG/name:${TAG}/g" Dockerfile'
```

Answer (score 1):

Guys try to this in your jenkinsfile

Use
`sh 'sed -i "s#name:TAG#name:${TAG.trim()}#" Dockerfile'`